# Why is it returning addresses as null?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Address Function :-

```
export const GetAddress = async (req, res) => {
  let user = req.user;
  try {
    if (!user) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "User not Found", success: false });
      return;
    }

    let id = await user.address[0];
    console.log(id);
    let addresses = await Address.findById(id);
    console.log(user);
    if (!addresses) {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: "No Address Found",
        success: false,
      });
      return;
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      message: `Welcome Back`,
      addresses,
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    ErrorHandler(res, error);
  }
};
```

UserData :-

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId('657be59e80baafa1288a5169'),
  firstName: '***',
  lastName: '**',
  email: '*******@gmail.com',
  password: '$2a$10$cfJUXElsffQaM6T0QCA03O5XomIyVhLgALE3auxQzkpgCysJLY0Ei',
  address: [
    new ObjectId('657da734d4f75aa0f22a051e'),
    new ObjectId('657da86fd4f75aa0f22a053a'),
    new ObjectId('657da8e0d4f75aa0f22a054e'),
    new ObjectId('657da9fbd4f75aa0f22a0552'),
    new ObjectId('657daa22d4f75aa0f22a0556')
  ],
  cart: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

Now as you can see I already have addresses in user's profile even after that if I try fetch a address using the address function it still throws the error

Comment: You have `let id = await user.address[0];` what is `user` in this context? You are using that id here `Address.findById(id);`. If `id` is `null` or `undefined` mongoose won't find an `Address`. Do a `console.log('req.user=', req.user);` as the first statement in your function to find out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is mongoose installed and imported?
2. In this line you're drawing data from req object (not from mongoose) so using 'await' isn't neccessary:

> ```
> let id = user.address[0];
> ```

in this line it is neccessary:

> ```
> let addresses = await Address.findById(id);
> ```

3. Most likely that instead of `req.user` you should access `req.body.user`

But - what is the object you sent into the request named - User or UserData?

4. Have you tried to refer to object id as `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`?

about mongoose objectId:
Output for ObjectId is a complex type (that contains value-kay pairs).

When inserting to db - the expected type should be <mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId> and then no conversion is needed.
Trying to read or compare ObjectId - adding .toHexString() is needed (because its a complex type) <User.address[0].toHexString()>

5. When printing it, it should be one of these two options:

> ```
> console.log(id.toHexString());
>
> console.log(req.body.user.address[0].toHexString());
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert ObjectId to string.

```
let id = await user.address[0]; // The type of id is ObjectId.
console.log(id);
let addresses = await Address.findById(id.toString()); // Convert ObjectId to string
```